# Where is the background image for windows stored?

Tags: windows-7

For the logon image where is the background image stored?

I have checked the registry with no success so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to know so that you can change the logon image?

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz...no I want the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can find the registry key to the logon image at :**

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background

**To change the logon image :**

1. Now, head over to the following folder:
   **C:\Windows\System32\oobe** (“C” is your Windows Seven Installation drive)
2. Here, create a new folder named **Info**. Again, create a new folder inside the Info folder and rename it as **backgrounds**.
3. Copy your favorite image file to this folder and rename it as backgroundDefault. Note that the image must be in JPG format and the size should be less than 256 KB.
4. You are done. Reboot your system and see the change.

The following files (sorted by width-to-height ratio) are supported in  C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\Backgrounds folder:

- backgroundDefault.jpg
- background768×1280.jpg  (0.6)
- background900×1440.jpg  (0.625)
- background960×1280.jpg  (0.75)
- background1024×1280.jpg (0.8)
- background1280×1024.jpg (1.25)
- background1024×768.jpg  (1.33-)
- background1280×960.jpg  (1.33-)
- background1600×1200.jpg (1.33-)
- background1440×900.jpg  (1.6)
- background1920×1200.jpg (1.6)
- background1280×768.jpg  (1.66-)
- background1360×768.jpg  (1.770833-)

And users who prefer to use a third-party instead can check out free tools such as Windows 7 Logon Screen Changer and Logon Screen Rotator to set your own picture as logon screen background withe a mouse click.

[Source](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-windows-7-logon-screen-easily-without-using-hacks-tools/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a bit late. But here is the storage location for the logon and lock screen background for Windows 7:

```
%WindowsDir%\System32\imageres.dll  
default location: C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll
```

You can view the *.jpg files embedded as resources in this DLL file with a resource editor such as Resource Hacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). There are several images for different resolutions.

also see this question on the MS forums: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/change-windows-7-logon-background-image/71f4281b-487a-405e-aa91-c65941838d00